# GraphQL not responding to requests made for express-session and redis

Tags: node.js, express, redis, graphql, apollo-server

I am trying to create a backend server for a dummy reddit clone. Whenever I request for a mutation that results in reading or writing to redis and session, I get an infinite loading time and the server never responds. I am using `postgresql` as my DB and `mikro-orm`. I am trying to integrate redis as a session store to the to the express server using `express-session`.

I have created 2 schemas for `graphQL`, one is for posts and one is for users. In the user schema, I have a `login` resolver which saves the user ID to the request as `session.userId`.

index.ts:

```js
import "reflect-metadata"
import { MikroORM } from "@mikro-orm/core"
import mikroConfig from "./mikro-orm.config"
import express from "express"
import { ApolloServer } from "apollo-server-express"
import { buildSchema } from "type-graphql"
import { HelloResolver } from "./resolvers/hello"
import { PostResolve } from "./resolvers/post"
import { UserResolver } from "./resolvers/user"
import * as redis from "redis"
import session from "express-session"
import connectRedis from "connect-redis"
import { __prod__ } from "./constants"
import { MyContext } from "./types"
// import { ApolloServerPluginLandingPageGraphQLPlayground } from "apollo-server-core"

const main = async () => {
    const orm = await MikroORM.init(mikroConfig)
    orm.getMigrator().up()

    const app = express()

    const RedisStore = connectRedis(session)
    const redisClient = redis.createClient({
        socket: {
            host: "127.0.0.1",
            port: 6379,
        },
    })

    await redisClient.connect()

    app.use(
        session({
            name: "qid",
            store: new RedisStore({
                client: redisClient,
                disableTouch: true,
            }),
            cookie: {
                maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 10, // 10 years
                httpOnly: true,
                sameSite: "none", // csrf
                secure: true, // cookie only works in https
            },
            saveUninitialized: false,
            secret: "keyboard cat",
            resave: false,
        })
    )

    const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
        schema: await buildSchema({
            resolvers: [HelloResolver, PostResolve, UserResolver],
            validate: false,
        }),
        context: ({ req, res }): MyContext => ({ em: orm.em, req, res }),
    })
    await apolloServer.start()
    apolloServer.applyMiddleware({
        app,
        cors: {
            origin: "https://studio.apollographql.com",
            credentials: true,
        },
    })
    app.listen(4002, () => {
        console.log("Example app listening on port 4002!")
    })
}
main().catch((err) => console.error(err))
```

My login resolver is as follows:

```js
@Mutation(() => UserResponse)
async login(
    @Arg("username") username: string,
    @Arg("password") password: string,
    @Ctx() { em, req }: MyContext
): Promise<UserResponse> {
    const user = await em.findOne(User, { username })
    if (!user) {
        return {
            errors: [{ field: "username", message: "that username doesn't exist" }],
        }
    }
    const valid = await argon2.verify(user.password, password)
    if (!valid) {
        return {
            errors: [{ field: "password", message: "incorrect password" }],
        }
    }
    req.session.userId = user.id

    return { user }
}
```

dependencies:

```json
{
    "@mikro-orm/cli": "^5.1.2",
    "@mikro-orm/core": "^5.1.2",
    "@mikro-orm/migrations": "^5.1.2",
    "@mikro-orm/postgresql": "^5.1.2",
    "apollo-server-core": "^3.6.7",
    "apollo-server-express": "^3.6.7",
    "argon2": "^0.28.5",
    "connect-redis": "^6.1.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.3",
    "express-session": "^1.17.2",
    "graphql": "^15.3.0",
    "pg": "^8.7.3",
    "redis": "^4.0.6",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "type-graphql": "^1.1.1"
}
```

I have a redis server running on WSL2 and I am able to see the logs of requests for set and get coming in but the response is not coming through to the frontend.

The source code can be found [here](https://github.com/singhdipesh14/express-graphql-react-redis).

I am following Ben Awad's [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I6ypD7qv3Z8) tutorial.

I cannot understand whether this is a problem with the redis, express or graphQL.

[Infinite Loading on Apollo Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9O2az.png)

I have tried shifting my whole setup to ubuntu, thinking it might be an error due to connecting to redis-server but I am able to reproduce this bug there as well.

I tried using the Apollo Playground and the same is happening there as well.

### Update:

According to the [docs](https://github.com/tj/connect-redis#api), if we're using `redis@4` we need to pass `legacyMode: true` when calling `createClient()`.
This is fixing the server not responding issue.

Thanks @robertklep

Comment: According to [the docs](https://github.com/tj/connect-redis#api), if you're using `redis@4` you need to pass `legacyMode: true` when calling `createClient()`. Have you tried that?

Comment: Thanks a lot @robertklep! Just tried it, and the server is now responding to the requests. The cookies are not yet being saved although, it looks like a cors error or cross-domain issue.

Comment: Update: Fixed the cookies issue as well, just had to add `x-forwarded-proto:https` header in apollo-studio settings as well as `app.set('trust proxy', 1)` for my express server to enable HTTP to HTTPS cookie setting.